# Moving location of dockerized GitLab data volumes

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am running GitLab using the 8.11.0-ce.1 image found [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/).  I configured my docker-compose volumes as so:

```
  volumes:
    - './data/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - './data/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - './data/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

However this disk has limited size and I wanted instead to move these volumes to /data/gitlab/ directory which is much larger.

In order to do this I tried the following steps:
1. Brought down the docker container
2. Copied the data volumes over (cp -r /app/gitlab/data/ /data/gitlab)
3. Modified the docker-compose.yml to

```
  volumes:
    - '/data/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/data/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '/data/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

However, upon restarting the container I get an error that repeats continously (see below).  I am assuming there is an additional step(s) that must be followed? Or am I going about this incorrectly?

```
gitlab_1  | Preparing services...
gitlab_1  | Starting services...
gitlab_1  | Configuring GitLab package...
gitlab_1  | Configuring GitLab...
gitlab_1  | /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 24: ulimit: pending signals: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
gitlab_1  | /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 34: ulimit: max user processes: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
gitlab_1  | /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start: line 37: /proc/sys/fs/file-max: Read-only file system
gitlab_1  |
gitlab_1  | ================================================================================
gitlab_1  | Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions]'
gitlab_1  | ================================================================================
gitlab_1  |
gitlab_1  | Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
gitlab_1  | ------------------------------------
gitlab_1  | Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
gitlab_1  | ---- Begin output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions ----
gitlab_1  | STDOUT:
gitlab_1  | STDERR: /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/logger.rb:703:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log (Errno::EACCES)
gitlab_1  |     from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/logger.rb:703:in `open'
gitlab_1  |     from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/logger.rb:703:in `open_logfile'
gitlab_1  |     from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/logger.rb:695:in `set_dev'
gitlab_1  |     from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/logger.rb:635:in `initialize'
gitlab_1  |     from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/logger.rb:353:in `new'
gitlab_1  |     from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/logger.rb:353:in `initialize'
gitlab_1  |     from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_logger.rb:15:in `new'
gitlab_1  |     from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_logger.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
gitlab_1  |     from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_keys.rb:4:in `require_relative'
gitlab_1  |     from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_keys.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
gitlab_1  |     from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
gitlab_1  |     from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
gitlab_1  |     from /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys:24:in `<main>'
gitlab_1  | ---- End output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions ----
gitlab_1  | Ran /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions returned 1
gitlab_1  |
gitlab_1  | Resource Declaration:
gitlab_1  | ---------------------
gitlab_1  | # In /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/gitlab-shell.rb
gitlab_1  |
gitlab_1  | 124: execute "#{gitlab_shell_keys_check} check-permissions" do
gitlab_1  | 125:   user git_user
gitlab_1  | 126:   group git_group
gitlab_1  | 127: end
gitlab_1  | 128:
gitlab_1  |
gitlab_1  | Compiled Resource:
gitlab_1  | ------------------
gitlab_1  | # Declared in /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/gitlab/recipes/gitlab-shell.rb:124:in `from_file'
gitlab_1  |
gitlab_1  | execute("/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions") do
gitlab_1  |   action [:run]
gitlab_1  |   retries 0
gitlab_1  |   retry_delay 2
gitlab_1  |   default_guard_interpreter :execute
gitlab_1  |   command "/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-keys check-permissions"
gitlab_1  |   backup 5
gitlab_1  |   group "git"
gitlab_1  |   returns 0
gitlab_1  |   user "git"
gitlab_1  |   declared_type :execute
gitlab_1  |   cookbook_name "gitlab"
gitlab_1  |   recipe_name "gitlab-shell"
gitlab_1  | end
gitlab_1  |
gitlab_1  | Platform:
gitlab_1  | ---------
gitlab_1  | x86_64-linux
gitlab_1  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** - Try using `cp -a` instead of `cp -r`

**Detail:**

I gave this a quick go using the compose file at https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#install-gitlab-using-docker-compose. I did  see the same error as you had.  This clearly looks to be some kind of permission problem.  I noticed there is a handy prompt when the container starts up, saying:

```
# docker-compose up
Recreating gitlab2_web_1
Attaching to gitlab2_web_1
web_1  | Thank you for using GitLab Docker Image!
web_1  | Current version: gitlab-ce=8.11.5-ce.0
web_1  |
web_1  | Configure GitLab for your system by editing /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file
web_1  | And restart this container to reload settings.
web_1  | To do it use docker exec:
web_1  |
web_1  |   docker exec -it gitlab vim /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
web_1  |   docker restart gitlab
web_1  |
web_1  | For a comprehensive list of configuration options please see the Omnibus GitLab readme
web_1  | https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md
web_1  |
web_1  | If this container fails to start due to permission problems try to fix it by executing:
web_1  |
web_1  |   docker exec -it gitlab update-permissions
web_1  |   docker restart gitlab
web_1  |
web_1  | Preparing services...
web_1  | Starting services...
```

I tried this with some limited success ... it's a little tricky to run as indicated because the container is continually restarting.  Since you're running via compose though, you can add:

```
entrypoint: update-permissions
```

i.e. something like this:

```
web:
  image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
  restart: always
  hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
  entrypoint: update-permissions
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
      # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
  ports:
    - '80:80'
    - '443:443'
    - '22:22'
  volumes:
    - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
    - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

to the relevant service config. It will recreate the container, but that's fine.  However, for me, I still seemed to have some problems with redis after I'd done that.

Since this is just files on a disk though, I figured I'd preserve ownership etc while copying, and this seemed to work fine. In your case, I guess that's:

```
cp -a /app/gitlab/data/ /data/gitlab
```

Comment: Thanks, that appears to have fixed the issue!  I think the permission message it shows on startup is for people moving from earlier versions of GitLab. I got the same Redis errors you were seeing.  Just using the -a flag works fine.

Answer (score 2):

### These are my steps for move a contenerized GitLab of location:

1. Run the new GitLab instance, for example:

   ```
   docker run --detach \
       --hostname gitlab.example.com \
       --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 \
       --name gitlab \
       --restart always \
       --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
       --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
       --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
       gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
   ```
2. After a moment stop the requiered services in your container, to avoid conflicts:

   ```
   docker exec -it gitlab /bin/bash -c 'gitlab-ctl stop unicorn && gitlab-ctl stop sidekiq && gitlab-ctl stop'
   ```
3. Copy the important data and configuration folders to the new GitLab
   container from the old GitLab. Assuming that your new GitLab container
   it's called **gitlab** and that your old GitLab volumes location is
   `/srv/` (see the reference of my volume location in the step 1):

   ```
   docker exec -it -u git gitlab /bin/bash -c 'rsync -avz user@SERVER_LOCATION:/srv/gitlab/config/* /etc/gitlab/'
   docker exec -it -u git gitlab /bin/bash -c 'rsync -avz user@SERVER_LOCATION:/srv/gitlab/logs/* /var/log/gitlab/'
   docker exec -it -u git gitlab /bin/bash -c 'rsync -avz user@SERVER_LOCATION:/srv/gitlab/data/* /var/opt/gitlab/
   ```

   (Replace `SERVER_LOCATION` for your location server. If you have the files in the same machine, use the `docker cp` command.)
4. Restart your container:

   ```
   docker restart gitlab
   ```
5. After few seconds (20 aprox. dependig of your machine) update the
   permissions files:

   ```
   docker exec -it gitlab /bin/bash -c "chown -R git /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/uploads && find /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/uploads -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \; && find /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/uploads -type d -not -path /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/uploads -exec chmod 0700 {} \;"
   docker exec -it gitlab /bin/bash -c 'update-permissions'
   ```

   For check the correctly work:

   ```
   docker exec -it gitlab /bin/bash -c 'gitlab-rake gitlab:check SANITIZE=true'
   ```

   (If in this step it's return any error, read the messange and apply the recomendation.)
6. Generate a backup of your initial migration (if you want):

   ```
   docker exec -it gitlab /bin/bash -c 'gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create'
   ```